# Copying files from Solaris to Linux

Tags: solaris, timestamps

I did a tar of a directory in a Solaris 10 box. I moved the file over to a SUSE 11.2 box and untarred the file into a directory. The dates are exactly the same but I notice that times that were before the time change this year are 1 hour ahead of the old server and dates after the time change are 2 hours ahead. I did this on 3 servers and it only happened on one server. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: It's kind of hard to follow your exact issue but it sounds to me like your servers may be set to different timezones, maybe some have daylight savings enabled/disabled while others don't, or the time on one is just an hour different than another.

Answer (score 1):

Like Jesse_b, my first thought was that it might be timezone related.

Have you tried using gtar on the Solaris box?  If so, you might get different results, and gtar might even have an option to use UTC.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

> The dates are exactly the same but I notice that times that were before the time change this year are 1 hour ahead of the old server and dates after the time change are 2 hours ahead.

Have the servers got different timezones ?

on Solaris: `/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo`
on Linux: `echo $TZ`

Do they correspond ?

My guess is they do not. Ensure the timezones are the same, both servers have the latest zone updates and you should be good to go.